# Getting celery to spread out across all tasks

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have multiple tasks I'd like to setup to execute in parallell.

- **Update packages**: returns a list of packages.
- **Update versions**: takes a package and returns a list of versions.
- **Update releases**: takes a version (for a package) and fetches releases.

Which gets me something like:

```
@task()
def update_packages():
    return [1, 2, 3]

@task()
def update_versions(package):
    # Get versions
    return [1, 2, 3]

@task()
def update_releases(version):
    # Get releases
```

What I can do is execute them in order and wait for the results, but I would rather push intermediate results forward, like on the shell:

```
update_packages | update_versions | update_releases
```

What invocation of magic would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for [groups](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#id7) and [Scatter-Gather](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/BroadcastAggregate.html) pattern:

```
@task()
def update_packages():
    res = group(update_versions.s(i) for i in [1, 2, 3])() # run tasks in parallel (Scatter)
    res.get() # wait for all results (Gather)
    return res

@task()
def update_versions(package):
    # Get versions
    res = group(update_packages.s(i) for i in [1, 2, 3])() # run tasks in parallel (Scatter)
    res.get() # wait for all results (Gather)
    return res

@task()
def update_releases(version):
    # Get releases
    return <what you want to see in final>
```

Now you can simple run `update_packages` and wait for all results:

```
res = update_packages()
```

You don't need to use `.delay`, because `update_packages` doesn't do any work by itself.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much what I ended up doing, I thought I could keep the jobs from not launching jobs and just chain them together, but this looks fine.